# How to remove file extension (.php) using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to rewrite

```
www.example.com/story.php?id=123&title=abc&cat=sports
```

to

```
www.example.com/story/123?title=abc&cat=sports
```

and i have used

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

its not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(story)\.php\?id=(\d+)&(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^story\.php$ /%1/%2?%3 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(story)/(\d+)/?$ /$1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

The above rules should work as needed.

Comment: i tried this but it shows " The requested URL /story.php was not found on this server." and i have tested this in "http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/" it shows error "RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(story)\.php\?id=(\d+)&(\S+) [NC] This variable is not supported: %{THE_REQUEST}". please help.

Comment: @ghost Provide the directory structure. Where is the `story.php` file located? Where are you putting the htaccess file
?

Comment: both htaccess and story.php are in root directory.

Comment: @ghost if the error shown is "_The requested URL /story.php was not found on this server_", then at least `story.php` is not in the root directory.

Comment: page is there . can  u check htaccess in http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ .
it shows "RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(story)\.php\?id=(\d+)&(\S+) [NC] This variable is not supported: %{THE_REQUEST}"

Comment: @ghost the htaccess.madewithlove.be page does not provide all the features available in the apache's rewrite module. They do have a disclaimer: _There are a couple of things which are not supported yet (like `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`) but we hope to add them in the future_.